# Order elements inside this array on the basis of frequency

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am facing this sort of array in the middle of a project. I want it to be sorted on the basis of ID frequency that means which id is repeated most has to come as first element of resulting array. How to do that??

In advance Thanks for help!!!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you want repeats in the output? e.g. {4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2}?

Comment: @EricM. i want array on the basis of repitition.. like 1st element would be 4 since it is repeated most, 2nd element would be 3 third element would be 2 and so on

Comment: See darrens method, its working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the above array is your structure, then something like this would do the trick for you, to organise the `id` with it's relevant counts:

```
$filtered = array_count_values(array_column($myArray, 'id'));
// now sort it: high - low
arsort($filtered);
```

Which results in the following array:

```
Array (
    [4] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [7] => 1
)
```

<sup>*With the above key's being the `id` column, and the values being the count of times it was present within the initial array*</sup>

My question to you is; *do you need it in it's original format, just ordered, or is a frequency display as above adequate*?

Comment: now if i need to access the top 2 id's which here is 4,1  what to do??

Comment: @beingbishwa either run a loop `foreach($filtered as $key => $count)` (*with `$key`, being the one you want*), or if you want the top 2, simply `$top2 = array_slice(array_keys($filtered), 0, 2);`

Comment: last question, if i want the result like this: array([1]=>4 , [2]=>1 , [3]=>1) and so on..so that i will have key as 1,2,3,4,5 and value be the most repeated ones order

Comment: @beingbishwa what do you mean like that? You want the keys to start at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: ohh i am sorry... of course i want keys to be started from 0.. could u help for that?

Comment: @beingbishwa Look at my 2nd option above - `$top2 = array_slice(array_keys($filtered), 0, 2);`, you can get 3 items by simply cutting 3 (*changing the 2 to 3*).

Comment: yeah!! i already figured out that.. anyway thanks so much for helping.. :)

Comment: @beingbishwa Pleasure mate!